# Simple timer class destroying itself for some reason

Tags: python, class, exception, time

I'm trying to make a simple timer class in python. The idea is to just call start() and stop() and it handles the work a little easier. It works as intended from one start() to stop(), but when I call start() again it throws an exception.

```
import time

class Timer:
    def start(self):
        self.start = time.time()
    def stop(self):
        print("Elapsed time: ",time.time()-self.start)

timer = Timer()
timer.start()
[i for i in range(100000)] #run something that takes a bit of time
timer.stop()
timer.start()
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Elapsed time:  0.007978439331054688
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath/imagepca.py", line 13, in <module>
    timer.start()
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see, the first start() works correctly, as does the stop(), but when I call start() again the program crashes. Why is this happening?

Comment: Your instance attribute and method have the same name. Just rename one of the two

Comment: yeah.. I totally agree. I think `self.start_time = time.time()` instead of `self.start = time.time()` will solve the problem

Comment: That's it, thank you! Tricky, the first call works fine because self.start wasn't defined, but any subsequent call would get confused because of the reason you described. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time

class Timer:
    def start(self):
        self.start = time.time()
    def stop(self):
        print("Elapsed time: ",time.time()-self.start)

timer = Timer()
timer.start()
[i for i in range(100000)] #run something that takes a bit of time
timer.stop()
timer.start()
```

This problem is coming due to the fact that you have function and instance variable with the same name.

```
import time

class Timer:
    def start(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
    def stop(self):
        print("Elapsed time: ",time.time()-self.start_time)
```

This will perfectly fine.